# How to detect taskbar position WPF

Tags: wpf, taskbar

I've created an app in C# / WPF with NoStyleBorder.

When I maximize my app all screen is recover by this, I use systemparameters values area for fix it.

But, If user change taskbar position like Bottom to Left, my app doesn't change position.

How to detect this changing position of the taskbar ?

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
WindowState="Maximized"
```

in XAML and in the Loaded-Event of the Window call

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        }
```

Comment: Good for the first launch but when I change taskbar position during runtime, windows not change this layout to corresponding to the new workarea size

Comment: Fot me it works on win10, with latest patches. What are you working on?